# How to add Azure Active Directory authentication to .Net Core static page as Teams Personal Tab

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I have a .Net Core 3.1 MVC project that serves a page to a Ms Teams personal page tab.
Authentication is a nightmare, because Teams runs the personal tab page in an iframe, which makes it impossible to use the normal authentication workflow.
There is a workaround, that triggers a new page with callbacks and I got it to work up to a point, but it doesn't actually perform the authentication against my website (it doesn't hit the controller when adding the [Authorize] attribute).
All the examples I found online are in node and it makes me wonder if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible.

This is my startup.cs relevant section

```
  services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

This is the part that calls the authentication using the microsoftTeams javascript SDK and receives the response correctly, but that's it.
I'm either missing a step, or the C# project is not configured properly. I need to mention the authentication works if I use it in a non-teams environment.

```
  function login(url) {
            hideProfileAndError();

            microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
                url: url,
                width: 600,
                height: 535,
                successCallback: function (result) {

                    var data = localStorage.getItem(result);
                    localStorage.removeItem(result);

                    var tokenResult = JSON.parse(data);
                    // showIdTokenAndClaims(tokenResult.idToken);
                    getUserProfile(tokenResult.accessToken);

                    console.log(tokenResult);
                },
                failureCallback: function (reason) {
                    console.log("Login failed: " + reason);
                    handleAuthError(reason);
                }
            });
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into Teams Tabs SSO (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso)?

Comment: The single sign on documentation also has one sample that uses node, which doesn't inspire a lot of confidence. I will give it a try if nothing else works, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question